# What is different in the Limited Edition version of Myst V: End of Ages?

Tags: myst-5-end-of-ages

GOG is currently selling *[Myst V: End of Ages Limited Edition](https://www.gog.com/game/myst_5_end_of_ages)*. What is different about this compared to the original edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not bought the game on GOG.com, but as far as I can tell, the original limited edition includes additional bonuses. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myst_V:_End_of_Ages) says the following:

> The limited edition contained the original soundtrack, a collector's lithograph, strategy guide, and a bonus DVD with a "making of" retrospective on the Myst franchise.

On [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000B1JKQI):

> Special Limited Edition contains: Bonus DVD with soundtrack, trailer and making-of documentary; Exclusive 152-page collector booklet with world-premiere preview of the new Myst book, The Book of Marrim.

The GOG.com version has the soundtrack and documentary as goodies. The physical items are of course missing. According to the store page there are no digital versions of the strategy guide (unless it is part of the manual) or preview of The Book of Marrim.

Comment: I appreciate you adding what the GOG version includes. I've decided to accept this answer for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick search on the Google, I've found out that a similar question has been answered on the Ubisoft forums, regarding the Limited Edition of Myst V, credit given to forum user [Alahmnat](http://forums.ubi.com/member.php/8599-Alahmnat?s=61cafee76d936d4a62dd868015ce059e): http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/546996-Myst-V-End-of-Ages-FAQ-Forums

To quote the forums,

> Q. Will there be a Collector's Edition?
>   A. According to UbiSoft's website, there will be a Limited Edition available in the US, which will include a 22-minute retrospective on the entire series, the official strategy guide from Prima Publishing, a frame-able print of game art, and the game soundtrack on a separate CD (Note: the soundtrack is not in a separate jewel case, but it does contain all 17 tracks and is a complete soundtrack).
>
> The European Collector's Edition contains different goodies in a book-shaped box, like the Revelation CE. The goodies include:

```
Exclusive bonus DVD with:
    25 minutes Making-of (encoded as DVD video, so you can watch it on the TV)
    Game soundtrack (7-track collection in .mp3 format, also contains a slideshow when played on the TV)
    Game trailers
Exclusive collector booklet (152 pages) including:
    Intro from Rand Miller
    Exclusive world-premiering preview of the new Myst book (“The Book of Marrim"‚ written by Rand Miller).
    D'ni language grammar & dictionary
    Previous Myst games overview
    Artwork gallery
    The booklet is broken down as such, according to RAWA, a Cyan staffer:
        the intro is 2 pages
        the BoM preview is 4 pages (it's the prologue)
        the D'ni language guide is about 20 pages
        the game overview is about 30 pages
        the gallery is about 35 pages
        the game manual, about 20 pages
        blank journal pages, about 35 pages
```

Comment: And now this question is now what shows up on a quick search on Google, which is a great thing!